# Android Studio: still getting warning, need to update 'compile' to 'implementation'

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

Ok, I know this question has been asked over and over and its usually something simple within your own build config that you need to update. However, I keeping seeing:

*Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.* warning message.

I have already checked that I am using the latest of the google services:

*'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'*

I've cleaned, rebuilt, invalidated cache with restart, and yet nothing changes. At this point my best guess is that this may be an underlying issue with 3rd party libs that I am importing. Could it be that they nay not be up to date with the *implementation* switch? Is there a way to find out which library would be the root cause, outside of me having to manually inspect each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. 
This warning message is normal as you may be using a later version of Android Studio with android gradle plugin 3.0 or above.

compile, provided, and apk are currently still available. However, they will be removed in the next major release of the Android plugin.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration for more details.

Comment: I've already replaced all of my own references from 'compile' to 'implementation' and/or 'api'. I get that they are still available until end of 2018, question is how can I quickly find which 3rd party libs haven't been updated, assuming that its a 3rd party lib that this project is using, without me having to investigate each one...

Comment: Can you provide your build.gradle file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot due to the contract terms signed for this project, not at liberty to disclose anything. If I was allowed I would have already, I know that's not helpful, but rest assured I have replaced ALL of the outdated references such as 'compile', 'debugCompile', and ''releaseCompile', etc...And if all I get is a comment 'I can't help without seeing it', then please dont bother responding. I honestly think its due to a 3rd part lib but because of how many 3rd party libs that this project has it would take a while to investigate each one. If there are no quick answers then so be it

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was a 3rd party lib/tool(s). The project I have inherited was including, but not actually using, [Freeline Build Tool](https://github.com/alibaba/freeline) & [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo). The moment I commented these out in both of the gradle files (project and app level) the warnings went away.